# Laravel Eloquent search multiple fields and relationship

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

I am trying to create a search query so that I can search the same string across a few different fields. The query also needs to search fields from the `machine_warranties` which is setup as a hasOne relationship on the `Machines` model.

Here's the warranty relationship in the Machines model

```
public function warranty()
{
    return $this->hasOne('App\MachineWarranty', 'machine_id');
}
```

Here's my attempt at the query. Searching for a serial or machine type works fine but I cannot figure out how to also search the relation.

```
Machine::orderBy('created_at', 'desc')
  ->where('serial', 'LIKE', '%' . $search . '%')
  ->orWhere('type', 'LIKE', '%' . $search . '%')
  ->with(['warranty' => function($query) use ($search) {
       $query->where('first_name', 'LIKE', '%' . $search . '%');
  }]);
```

Is there a way to do `->orWith()` maybe?

Comment: your query seems ok, is there any error??

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the [`orWhereHas()`](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/eloquent-relationships#querying-relationship-existence) method:

```
Machine::latest()
    ->where('serial', 'like', '%' . $search . '%')
    ->orWhere('type', 'like', '%' . $search . '%')
    ->orWhereHas('warranty', function($q) use($search) {
        $q->where('first_name', 'like', '%' . $search . '%');
    })
    ->get();
```

Answer (score 2):

Use `whereHas()` to make `and` query:

```
Machine::orderBy('created_at', 'desc')
->where('serial', 'LIKE', '%' . $search . '%')
->orWhere('type', 'LIKE', '%' . $search . '%')
->with('warranty')
->whereHas('warranty' , function($query) use ($search) {
   $query->where('first_name', 'LIKE', '%' . $search . '%');
})->get();
```