# How sum data on table with 4 conditions

Tags: php, laravel

I want to display the total amount from start date and end date from tgl_trans, nasabah_id, jenis_id ??

```
$start = Carbon::parse($request->input('start'))->startOfDay();
$end = Carbon::parse($request->input('end'))->endOfDay();
$query = Transaksi::whereDate('tgl_trans', '>=', $start)->whereDate('tgl_trans', '<=', $end)->where('nasabah_id', $id)->get();

$kredit = $query->where('jenis_id', 1)->sum('nominal'); //result 0
```

Table transaksi

```
Schema::create('transaksis', function (Blueprint $table) {
$table->id();
$table->string('kode_trans');
$table->('nasabah_id');
$table->decimal('saldo_awal', $precision = 15, $scale = 2)->nullable();            
$table->unsignedBigInteger('jenis_id');
$table->foreign('jenis_id')->references('id')->on('jenis')->onDelete('cascade')->onUpdate('cascade');
$table->decimal('nominal', $precision = 15, $scale = 2)->nullable();
$table->decimal('saldo', $precision = 15, $scale = 2)->nullable();
$table->integer('diff_day')->nullable();
$table->unsignedBigInteger('user_id');
$table->date('tgl_trans');
$table->timestamps(); });
```

value on $kredit not 0

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Laravel Eloquent search multiple fields and relationship](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48807337/laravel-eloquent-search-multiple-fields-and-relationship)

Comment: Hello again! This question more better than yesterday.. `$kredit = Transaksi::whereDate('tgl_trans', '>=', $start)->whereDate('tgl_trans', '<=', $end)->where('nasabah_id', $id)->where('jenis_id', 1)->sum('nominal');`

Comment: I have tried wahyu, result is 0

Answer (score 0):

Hard to debug the code, so I'll leave a few suggestions:

Make sure that the `$id` exists, is set, and is not null/zero (i.e. is valid).

```
if (!$id){
    dd("ID is empty");
}
```

check if the query is empty

```
(...)
$query = Transaksi::whereDate('tgl_trans', '>=', $start)
         ->whereDate('tgl_trans', '<=', $end)
         ->where('nasabah_id', $id)
         ->get();

if ($query->isEmpty()){
    dd("the result was empty");
}}
(...)
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all your migration file at line no-3 columns data type should be

```
$table->unsignedBigInteger('nasabah_id');
```

Other all I tried myself was ok with [image: TableData] & output , you may try by entering menual data as flowing

```
        $tod = date("2022-05-15");
        $start = Carbon::parse($tod)->startOfDay();
        $end = Carbon::parse(now())->endOfDay();
        $id = 5;

        $kredit = Transaksi::whereDate('tgl_trans', '>=', $start)
                    ->whereDate('tgl_trans', '<=', $end)
                    ->where('nasabah_id', $id)
                    ->where('jenis_id', 10)
                    ->sum('nominal');

        return response($kredit);
    }
```

If its ok, then you have to check you requested input fields else you may check your database data.
Hope it will help.